# how to pass command line argument to a script which should be run in the background?

Tags: perl, bash

How to pass command line argument to a script which should be run in the background?
I tried the below command and it gives an error:

```
system("perl sample.pl& 1");
Error: 1: command not found
```

Answer (score 3):

Arguments to the program being run in the background have to be placed before the ampersand:

```
perl sample.pl 1 &
```

What you typed is recognized by the shell (I'm assuming you're on a Unix or Linux variant) as 2 separate commands:

```
perl sample.pl
```

which is run in the background, and

```
1
```

Where the shell is reporting that 1 is not a valid command.

Comment: a way to see it : ";" (or "return") terminates a command. and "&" terminates a command + places it in the background.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that does not work is due to the all arguments must be before the ampersand

So `system("perl sample.pl 1 &");`

Alternatively you can use exec() or backticks. For example `` `perl sample.pl 1 &` ``

If you use exec though, just know it never returns where system does.